# How to make my countdown timer go up once it reaches 00:00 using javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I was trying to make a countdown timer that once it reaches " 00:00 " it should go up again without limit.

I can't figure it out how to make my countdown go up once it reaches " 00:00 " maybe you can help me.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Countdown</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
// set minutes
var mins = 1;

 // calculate the seconds (don't change this! unless time progresses at a               different speed for you...)
var secs = mins * 60;
var timeout;

function countdown() {
 timeout = setTimeout('Decrement()', 1000);
}


function colorchange(minutes, seconds)
{
 if(minutes.value =="00" && seconds.value =="59")
 {
minutes.style.color="orange";
seconds.style.color="orange";
 }
  else if(minutes.value =="00" && seconds.value =="30")
{
minutes.style.color="red";
seconds.style.color="red";
 }

}

function Decrement() {
if (document.getElementById) {
minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
// if less than a minute remaining

if (seconds < 59) {
seconds.value = secs;

} else {
  minutes.value = getminutes();
  seconds.value = getseconds();
}
colorchange(minutes,seconds);

secs--;
if (secs < 0) {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  return;
}
countdown();
 }
 }

 function getminutes() {
  // minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
 mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  return ("0" + mins).substr(-2);
   }

  function getseconds() {
  // take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
  return ("0" + (secs - Math.round(mins * 60))).substr(-2);
   }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="timer">
 This is only valid for the next <input id="minutes" type="text"       style="width: 110px; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 100px;    font-weight: bold;"> :
 <input id="seconds" type="text" style="width: 110px; border: none;        background-color:none; font-size: 100px; font-weight: bold;"> 
</div>
<script>
countdown();
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your current solution is a little overcomplicated. You have a function that sets a timeout that calls another function which does the work and then re-calls the function that sets the timeout again.

Instead of doing that, just use the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) method instead.

Similarly to what @JoColina suggested, set a `direction` variable that indicates which direction to count, and then set up different behavior for counting up vs. counting down.

```js
var direction = 'down';
var mins = 1.1;
var secs = mins * 60;

function colorchange() {
  var className;
  if (direction == 'up') {
    className = 'success';
  } else if (secs <= 30) {
    className = 'danger';
  } else if (secs <= 59) {
    className = 'warning';
  }
  document.getElementById('timeText').className = className;
}

function getminutes() {
  // minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
  mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  return ("0" + mins).substr(-2);
}

function getseconds() {
  // take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
  return ("0" + (secs - Math.round(mins * 60))).substr(-2);
}

function countdown() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var minutes = document.getElementById('minutes');
    var seconds = document.getElementById('seconds');

    minutes.value = getminutes();
    seconds.value = getseconds();
    colorchange();

    if (direction == 'down') {
      secs--;
      if (secs <= 0) {
        direction = 'up';
      }
    } else if (direction == 'up') {
      secs++;
    }
  }, 1000);
}


countdown();
```

```css
.success,
.success input {
  color: green;
}

.warning,
.warning input {
  color: orange;
}

.danger,
.danger input {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer">
  This is only valid for the next
  <span id="timeText">
    <input id="minutes" type="text" style="width: 110px; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 100px; font-weight: bold;">:
    <input id="seconds" type="text" style="width: 110px; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 100px; font-weight: bold;">
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do the seconds go 2 on 2 like 02:54 and then 02:52 ?

Comment: I don't see that happening. Are you seeing something like that when you click the **Run code snippet** button in my answer?

Comment: The snippet code seems to work fine but in my timer it doesn't work like that.

Comment: Nvm , I found out what was the problem , thanks btw.

Comment: How do I make the colon between the timer change color as the numbers?

Comment: See my edited solution. I changed it to use classes for changing the colors. It is best to use stylesheets and avoid inline styles when possible. I also added an extra container for just the time text so that we can just change the class on that one element in order for the color change to apply to the child elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

`tl;dr`, however you could declare a global boolean like `var down = true;`, and once your timer reaches 00:00, you just change `down = true` to `down = false`.

Then, on the function that changes the counter you add:

```
if(down){
    Decrement();
}else{
    Increment():
}
```

And if, for example, you want to decrement again once it reaches `13:54` you once more add a `down = true`.

Hope this helps!